# How to make burp catch flow from aplication on localhost?

Tags: localhost, burp

I'm trying to learn penetration testing but I have small problem. Aplication, what I want to test is not showing me any data in burp after I setup everything as always:

1. Start Burp and intercept on (running 127.0.0.1:8080)
2. Browser setup:

[image: browser setup]

My aplication running at http://localhost:52054/ .

Do someone know how to set it up so I can catch flow?

Answer (score 0):

We have had reports of this happening with IIS Express.

You can workaround by editing your hosts file to make another hostname (e.g. myhost) resolve to 127.0.0.1. You can then browse to http://myhost/ and the traffic will be proxied through Burp.

Comment: Didn't worked. I setuped it this way and I can ping on localhost with "ping myhost" but aplication is not working on http://myhost:52054/                                                   
                                                                                                                             
[hosts settings here](https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/06/26/BLBv.png)

Comment: @battle44 - what web server is running on myhost:52054

Comment: Application is coded in way, that it can run only on localhost (myhost is not working for it - i tryed to change it but something went wrong). It is aplication based on .net and MVC. I suppose this might not be problem with burp.